# Feedback on my Music Video Without Music

Tags: design, music, sound, video, critique

I'm looking for a bit of feedback on this work I'm doing for my portfolio. https://vimeo.com/96135692

Comment: @AJHenderson A "Music Video Without Music" is a produced pop music video that has had the original audio track replaced with sound effects and raw vocals. OP is asking for critique on his sound design--this has nothing to do with video production.

Comment: ([see also](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f6ZSZbNfSpk))

Comment: @nreilingh ah, still not sure if the critique fits well, but thanks for explaining what it is.